# Is the Higgs field part of space?

Tags: cosmology, higgs

So I looked for some explanations, how I understand it so far is that the Higgs field causes particles to have mass by drag, like drag force in water, which prevents objects from moving at the speed of light, is that correct? so is the Higgs field essentially an element that makes up space?

Comment: Fields aren't elements that make up space. Rather, they are conditions on space. Think of them as mathematical functions that assign a physical quantity to each point in space and time. For instance, the electric field assigns an electric field vector to each point of space. The Higgs field assigns four component complex scalar from SU(2) to each point of spacetime, instead of assigning a vector to each point. So we call it a Higgs field instead of a vector field.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to leave this as a comment, but this Youtube video by Sean Carroll answers your question very well. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwdY7Eqyguo

Answer (score 1):

The Higgs field is *in* space (time), space is not made of it. Like any other field, mathematically it is a function that takes a value (usually a number) at each point in spacetime.

Now, for most fields the default value is zero. By "default" I mean the state of least energy; if you want a nonzero value you have to put energy in. The thing about the Higgs field is that its least energy state is a definite nonzero value. This in turn implies that if any field is coupled to the Higgs, it will experience a sort of constant interaction, which manifests itself as a mass; this mass is related to the strength of the interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Higgs field as I understand is everywhere.

The interaction of an elementary particle with higgs field gives resistance to accelerate, is what we call mass.

Some particles simple does not interact with higgs field (photons, gluons) and they have no mass.

Heavier particles interact more.

As long a particle becomes closer to speed of light more energy is necessary to accelerate it. Infinite energy is necessary to accelerate it if it is infinitely close to speed of light.

As I understand, Higgs field give mass, accelerate a particle is linked with special relativity, and I don't think both have a direct relation.

Answer (score 0):

A Higgs field, in a simple analogy, can be thought of as friction. The more other objects rub/interact with air molecules, the more they slow down and the more the air molecules move around.

However, I believe that the Higgs boson particle cannot be everywhere since for that to occur, the law of conservation of mass would be violated, and the universe would expand more and more Higgs boson particles would be created. Instead, what if the universe only had a finite amount of Higgs boson particles that would still generate a field since the space between two Higgs boson particles is undefined since a property of matter is mass? This way the field can still be represented as a function. Hence, particles can travel faster than the speed of light; however, in this state, they cannot be measured. Remember that this is a theory derived from logical reasoning and observation of how the universe was formed.